# Epi Twitter Api Question

Tags: php

The Epi Twitter API files [here](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/files/jaisenmathai_com_oauth_test.zip) do all but allow for the oauth_callback URL to be set. Does anyone know the code to add this?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tutorials out there that can show you how to integrate EpiTwitter into your code. What you want to do is pass

```
"oauth_callback" => "http://www.callbackurl.com"
```

to the HttpRequest() function as a parameter. I suggest looking through the EpiOAuth.php file and see if you can find where the parameters are passed (hint: look in the function arguments for $params).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/) or I suggest you to use the [Abraham twitter oauth class](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)

Otherwise do following steps:

1. Write your consumer key and consumer secret in `secret.php`
2. Write your *Registered OAuth Callback URL* in your [twitter application](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/) (if testing on `localhost` then write `http://127.0.0.1/yourfoldername` )
3. Then run `start.php` and see the response